# Как найти значение в массиве по другому полю

Tags: php

Есть массив с данными, в нем поля `id`, `code`, `name` мне известно значение `code` и по этому значению, я хочу вернуть из массива значение `id`, как это сделать?

Ну например в sql : `select id from someArray where code = 'somecode';` Как из массива выдернуть так же значение `id`?

Comment: Приведите пример массива

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно извлечь столбец `code` из массива,  найти в нем нужный элемент, и взять `id` по соовтетствюущему индексу

```
$data = [ .... ];
$needle = "find-me";

$idx = array_search($needle, array_column($data, 'code'));
$result = $data[$idx]['id'];
```

можно банально узнать то же самое в цикле

```
foreach($data as $d){
    if($d['id'] == $needle){
         $result = $d['id'];
         break;
    }
}
```

Или вараант с `array_reduce`, хотя он менее удобен и менее эффективен

```
$id  = array_reduce($data, function($res, $item) use ($needle){
              if($res) return $res;
              if($item['code'] == $needle) return $item['id'];
           }, null);
```

Comment: Первый вариант самое то, спасибо!